# How can I create an application for Windows ?

Tags: visual-studio, windows, software-distribution

I'm planning on developing simple applications on small scale for real-time problem like a software for replacing a Ledger. Can I use Visual Studio Community for the purpose. Will i be able to share the .exe file to any computer?

Comment: Yes. and Yes. And please, next time ask a specific question for us to solve. Voting to close the question.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Thank you. And sure next time :)